# ADSL disconnect every few minutes

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My internet connection lost every few minutes.
This is the log from the router.

N600 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit VDSL2 Modem Router
Model No. TD-W9980

```
302 2017-04-21 14:04:11 PPP Information ppp0 rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x439812ff]
303 2017-04-21 14:04:11 PPP Information ppp0 sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="**email**" password=<hidden>]
304 2017-04-21 14:04:11 PPP Information ppp0 sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x33a3b7c3]
305 2017-04-21 14:04:11 PPP Information ppp0 rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <mru 1492> <magic 0x33a3b7c3>]
306 2017-04-21 14:04:11 PPP Information ppp0 sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x8b <mru 1492> <auth pap> <magic 0x439812ff>]
307 2017-04-21 14:04:11 PPP Information ppp0 rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x8b <mru 1492> <auth pap> <magic 0x439812ff>]
308 2017-04-21 14:04:11 PPP Information ppp0 sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mru 1492> <magic 0x33a3b7c3>]
309 2017-04-21 14:04:11 PPP Information ppp0 sent [PADI Host-Uniq(0x00001d83)]
310 2017-04-21 14:04:08 DSL Notice  xDSL Enter Showtime!!
311 2017-04-21 14:04:03 DHCPD   Notice  Recv INFORM from **MAC**
312 2017-04-21 14:03:43 DSL Notice  xDSL Training!!
313 2017-04-21 14:03:42 PPP Error   ppp0
314 2017-04-21 14:03:42 PPP Error   ppp0 User request
315 2017-04-21 14:03:40 DSL Notice  xDSL Handshake!!
316 2017-04-21 14:03:39 PPP Information ppp0 sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "User request"]
317 2017-04-21 14:03:36 PPP Information ppp0 sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "User request"]
318 2017-04-21 14:03:36 PPP Warning ppp0 LCP down
319 2017-04-21 14:03:36 PPP Error   ppp0 LCP down
320 2017-04-21 14:03:36 PPP Error   ppp0 User request
321 2017-04-21 14:03:35 DSL Notice  xDSL Ready!!
322 2017-04-21 14:03:32 DSL Notice  xDSL Leave Showtime!!
323 2017-04-21 14:03:31 DSL Notice  xDSL Leave Showtime!!
```

Comment: Have you contacted your ISP to report the problem?

Comment: Yes, It's repeat itself for over a month,  they said the problem is in my home network. But i checked all the clients and i thing the problem it's not my. What the exact meaning of the problem?

Comment: If your ISP says the line is good, have you tried a different modem.  perhaps the modem is on its way out.

Comment: Yep, I bought a new one, same problem. Whats the meaning of the problems in the log?

Comment: What they probably mean is commonly referred to as "Inside Wiring" in the industry. That is the point from the NID (Network Interface Device) where the cables come off the street into a box at the side of the house. From that box on, it is your responsibility. Most NID boxes have jacks you can plug into, test the connection from that jack and see if the problem persists. If it does, call your ISP, it is their problem. If it doesn't, it is wiring in the house and it is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here IS NOT your LAN. It's quite clearly an issue between your modem and your ISP - and if you were advised otherwise the person who advised you is incompetent in the extreme.

The issue could be with your home wiring or a phone or device plugged into the phone network or a fault in the cabling between you and the ADSL port on the ISP side, or a faulty port.

You can eliminate the possibility of a faulty device by unplugging all phone extensions and plugging the modem directly into the phone line (you may need a different cable). If the problem goes away, gradually add back devices - starting with the ADSL splitter on your ADSL modem until the problem recurs. Note that your ADSL splitter could be failty. - you might want to replace it.

If you don't have ADSL filters and everything used to work, and you have not changed the config, you need to get the telco to look into it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already did that, and I got the same problem while I unplugged all the network clients and phone devices, also I skipped the filter and connected the modem directly.